# TypeError: set_ticks() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to run the example of a heatmap from: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html

When I am running the code in PyCharm (Professional) in an Anaconda3 environment it results in an error message.

> TypeError: set_ticks() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'

Comment: maybe your matplotlib version is too old? otherwise i have no idea.

Comment: The `labels=` keyword for `set_xticks()` is new since matplotlib 3.5.   In older versions, you can call `set_xticks()` with the tick positions and `set_xticklabels()` with the corresponding labels.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to update the matplotlib version in my directory. Now it works fine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to update matplotlib version if you are using version of matplotlib 3.4.3.

Here is the link for matplotlib 3.4.3 [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.4.3/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-image-annotated-heatmap-py) and avoid using labels keyword in `ax.set_xticks()` function as said by JohnC

Comment: It works with version 3.7.4 but not with 3.4.3